# Working with parent child relationships in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi

I am working with data that is structured in a parent-child relationship. Every level already has the rolled-up value (sum of the children). Therefore, I want Power Bi to display the value that is shown at every level (or sum on the same level) and not aggregate between parent and child. Also, the sums of the children don't always equal the parents, because some details are missing at the lower level. I do still need the parent-child relationship in PowerBi for drill through purposes. Attached is an example of how the data is structured. The table on the left is how I receive it. I have a dynamic number of levels, so ideally the solution wouldn't have a hard-coded number of levels. Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no way around having a fixed number of levels in PowerBI, but you can easily write a measure that takes the MAX rather than the SUM of the values.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. So I still need to be able to sum the values on the same level, just not the parent with the child.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply these below steps to your table in **Advanced Editor** to get your desired output. Please replace the **previous_step_name** name (my frst step) accordingly to make this code functional.

```
let
    //Your previous steps,

    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"previous_step_name", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    tab_before_split = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Index",{"Index", "Item", "Value"}),
    tab_split = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"tab_before_split", {{"Item", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("/", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Item"),
    tab_group_by = Table.Group(#"tab_split",{"Index"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
    tab_new = Table.Join(tab_before_split,"Index", tab_group_by,"Index"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(tab_new, "Item", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("/", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Item.1", "Item.2", "Item.3"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Item.1", type text}, {"Item.2", type text}, {"Item.3", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Level", each [Count] - 1),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Count"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Level", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```

Sample input-

[image]

Sample output-

[image]

Comment: thanks. Would you know how I proceed from there? How would I use that Level column?

Comment: depends where you wants to use that column. the output is just your explained requirement.